# Skip is not a member of System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection(of System.Data.DataRow)

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am working on jqGrid paging and it was working perfectly ok when I was working in a separate application. I moved it to the existing project and keep getting this error.

And If I try and add reference to System.Data.DataSetExtensions it says it doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found.

[image]

Comment: Have you got `Imports System.Linq`?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me in my project, where table is a Datatable, and this code builds fine.

```
table.AsEnumerable().Skip(5).Take(5)
```

Are you missing any necessary import statements and DLL references for some reason?  Is dtWORData a DataTable object directly, right?  Seems like yes, because your popup lists EnumerableRowCollection, which my example shows too when I mouse over it in visual studio.